# New Google Map Api for Java app, add the map in a JPanel

Tags: java, api, google-maps

As you maybe know, the Google Map API has changed few months ago and the way to implement it in a JPanel changed as well. I was looking for a solution all week and never found it.

I found some tests from google on github but it never show how to put it in an interface.

So does someone know how to put a Google Map (from the new Google Map API) in a JPanel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still embed a web browser such as the on in JavaFX and use the normal google maps example html+javascript and make javascript calls through that browser component. Though beware that the browser component in javafx has had severe issues with google maps in the past. Some versions have worked great, some not so much...

A high performance prepared java swing component that is a wrapper around chromium browser for google maps with pure java api:s is available for commercial and open source:
https://www.teamdev.com/jxmaps

Trying their demo it shows great performance (I've no affiliation).